# Sintaxis in xml request of Acumatica Export

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, acumatica

I have a struggle for setting up a FILTER for my xml request for Acumatica.
Without filters this works fine. But when i include any filter I receive a BLANK response.

I believe I have an issue with a sintaxis.
Could you please advice me where I am wrong?

```
 <commands>
   <Command>
     <FieldName>InventoryCD</FieldName>
     <ObjectName>Item</ObjectName>
     <Value>Inventory</Value>
       <Commit>1</Commit>
       <IgnoreError>0</IgnoreError>
       <LinkedCommand>
       <FieldName>InventoryCD</FieldName>
       <ObjectName>Item</ObjectName>
       <Value>[Item.InventoryCD]</Value>
       <Commit>1</Commit>
       <IgnoreError>0</IgnoreError>
       <LinkedCommand xsi:nil=""true"" />
       <Descriptor xsi:nil=""true"" />
    </LinkedCommand>

   </Command>
   <Command>
   <FieldName>InventoryCD!Descr</FieldName>
     <ObjectName>Item</ObjectName>
     <Value>Description</Value>
   </Command>

    <Command>
   <FieldName>AlternateID</FieldName>
     <ObjectName>itemxrefrecords</ObjectName>
     <Value>Manufacturer P/N</Value>
   </Command>
  </commands>


<filters>
    <Filter>
      <Field = InventoryCD.Item.Inventory/>
      <Condition>Contain</Condition>
      <Value = ""300""/>

    </Filter>
 </filters>


 <topCount>10</topCount>
 <includeHeaders>1</includeHeaders>
 <breakOnError>1</breakOnError>
```

Answer (score 0):

So this fixed my problem

```
<filters>
    <Filter>
        <Field>
            <FieldName>InventoryCD</FieldName>
            <ObjectName>Item</ObjectName>
            <Value>Inventory</Value>
        </Field>
        <Condition>StartsWith</Condition>
        <Value xsi:type="xsd:string" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">300</Value>
        <OpenBrackets>0</OpenBrackets>
        <CloseBrackets>0</CloseBrackets>
    </Filter>
</filters>
```

cheers.